# @Pattern regex doesn't check empty values

Tags: java, regex, bean-validation

I have an input field where a SIM number has to be entered. For that field in the bean I put the following validation expression:

```
@Pattern( regexp = "^(?:\\d{19})$", message = "{validation.notValidSIMNumber}" )
```

which should be "only 19-digit numbers are accepted".

I expected that if the field is left empty, the validation would also claim.

But instead there is no error message...

EDIT:
Sorry, I wrote the false regex (with | at the end).
So, to be clear: I need to validate an input field and it must be a 19-digit number. No possibility to leave it empty.

With the above regex, if I leave it empty I get no error message, but as soon as I enter something that's not a 19-digit number I get the error message.

Comment: Are empty values "ok" or not ? If it's not what you want then remove `|`. It means "or". Since you have nothing after it, it will validate empty string

Comment: I have no experience in bean-validation, but it sounds like something that cannot be checked from an entry field alone. You should perhaps have a check when the user submits the form or whatever and make sure that every mandatory field is not empty. It wouldn't make sense to prevent an entry field being empty when a user is shown the form, because otherwise, the user will be getting error messages before doing anything at all.

Comment: @Jerry you're maybe right; there is the annotation `@NotNull`, but I just thought that the `@Pattern` is "stronger" and could include the first too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `^\\d{19}$`  should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is  : `^(?:\\d{19}|)$`

[image]

Change your code to :

```
@Pattern( regexp = "^(?:\\d{19})$|^$", message = "{validation.notValidSIMNumber}" )
```

**EXPLANATION :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
System.out.println("1234567891234568977".matches("^[0-9]{19}$"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you are in need of matching 19 digit number and it too be the beginning and end of line it seems.

So for that you can use (^(\d{19})$)* - as it matches only the sentence containing 19 digits or an empty line (without any digits or characters).